# macports vim with +keymap option

Tags: vim, osx-lion, macports, keymapping

I've got a Mac OS X Lion. And there's a vim, that is installed from macports. Unfortunately, it lacks a +keymap option. Is there a way I can install vim from macports with this additional option?
As far as I know, ports fetch vim sources and compile them. If so, there might be a way how to hold on ports installation process to introduce one small change to makefile. Do you know one?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim provides several feature sets, which can be selected by variants in MacPorts. The normal build does not include this keymap feature, you would need +big or even +huge.

For a new install:

```
sudo port install vim +big
```

Or, to add the +big variant to an existing installation:

```
sudo port -n upgrade --enforce-variants vim +big
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to just use CLI executable found in the latest MacVim build. I think it comes with this option.